# Monte Carlo map's given?

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm trying to program a Monte Carlo Localization.
I know the algorithm steps.
1-Initizalization (particles and pose robot)
2-Sensor update (get lidar data, matching with the map and give weights to each particle)
3-Resampling related to weight.
3-Motion update (move particles related to odometry sensor)
4-Sensor update and so on.

My problem is in step 2. I don't know how to do the matching with the map with sensor data... I don't know the equation or how to do it.
So my question is how to give weight to particles with a map given.

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276448/monte-carlo-map%27s-given?/) by [Alvaro.S](https://answers.ros.org/users/32716/alvaro.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is too much to answer on this Forum/Q&A-page, as this really relates to the core aspects of the respective algorithm.

However, as this is pretty standard, there are a lot of papers, books and examples around.
Either check how it is done in [`amcl`](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) which stands for "Adaptive Monte Carlo Localization", read the book [Probabilistic Robotics, Ch. 8.3](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/) by Fox, Burgard and Thrun or check for papers or other sources.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1